# Managing different sized contents in a card

Tags: text, content, cards, size

How to manage different size of contents in a card, keeping the card size same?

[image: Sample Design]

Comment: This looks like a CSS question perhaps but have you looked at flexbox?  With it you can ensure the boxes are all the same height and then I would bottom align the CTA button.

Comment: I can be wrong but flexbox will not show all cards with same height without javascript. I suggest to use the grid and I also suggest you make this question at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I mean from a design perspective, not a CSS question.

I got some inconsistencies when the real data is put in this design.

I want to have the box to be the same size.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with using css flexbox. The `align-items: stretch` is the property that should be applied to the container of the Cards.

See the `align-items` explanation here for more info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

This will make all Cards equal to the card with the greatest height. Then you can make sure all of the “mapped” buttons are aligned across the cards.